# Low-graphics mode error in 13.04 with no graphics card

Tags: graphics

When I try to boot my computer, I get this error:

> The system is running in low-graphics mode
>   Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.

The LIKELY causes like installation of wrong drivers, incorrect or invalid lightdm greeters, low disk space, incorrect installation of graphics card like ATI and Nvidia, incorrect configuration of xorg.conf file while setting up multiple monitors are not what is causing this as

- I have No graphics card.
- No additional drivers.
- I freed space too.
- I reinstalled desktop too.
- I checked `lightdm.config` too. It already had

  ```
  greeter-session=unity-greeter
  ```
- I did this too. `sudo apt-get install fglrx`  `sudo reboot` No idea what this does but this was one of the solutions provided.
- And this too.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -d install --reinstall gdm
  sudo apt-get remove --purge gdm
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo reboot
  ```

Now I have no desktop in failsafe mode in ubuntu.

Now what do I do?
I HAVE TRIED THE SOLUTIONS PROVIDED FOR [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). They didn't work.

Comment: can you exlain the problem clearly. And which brand are you using?

Comment: I have Toshiba Satellite A205 and Ubuntu 13.04. And I have tried the solutions provided for[How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error). @krishnakanthreddy

Comment: did your system worked perfectly before?

Comment: Yes. It was working fine.@krishnakanthreddy

Comment: "I have No graphics card" what you mean with this?

Comment: @asd123 As can I see from http://www.cnet.com/laptops/toshiba-satellite-a205-s5804/4507-3121_7-32815151.html, your laptop has a graphics card and it's called "Intel GMA X3100". That's normal because every laptop has a screen and to see something on that screen you need a graphics card. So if you have concluded that your laptop has no video card, I'm sure that you missed something somewhere trying [these answers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command: `cd /etc/X11/` and run this command `sudo cp xorg.conf.failsafe xorg.conf` now reboot your system

Comment: With what reason? And what if there doesn't exist such a file?

Comment: I didn't know what reason, but this file contains graphics configurations, such as Device identifiers for video device configuration

Comment: So, if you copy a file from one place to another do you think that you solve this problem? No, this problem is a little bit more complicated; see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error

Comment: I experienced this kind of problem and also use that solution you mentioned, but that solution didn't work. I use my own solution to solve this low graphics problem.